# Inside the construction of the Frey curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Consider the frey curve $E\mathrel: y^2=x(x-a^{p})(x+b^{p})$ with conductor   $N =2\prod_{p|(abc)^{2p}}p $.  Frey assume that $p$ does not divide $(abc)^{2p} $ so the level of the cusp form predict by Ribet's theorem  is equal to 2  and no  modular form exists
But in the paper of G. Frey, "[Links between stable elliptic curves and certain Diophantine equations](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Links-between-stable-elliptic-curves-and-certain-Frey/ae817e39c348dc7ef5a8b2f98be2c4202a933da0)" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=853387)), in a remark on page 16, Frey said that, when $p$ does not divide $(abc)^{2p}$, this is called the first case of Fermat. 
But what happen if $p \mid (abc)^{2p}$; what about the second case?is that true ? I mean buy that , Does we can do this for another curve ?for example let E be an elliptic curve with discriminant
$\Delta$=$2^{2\alpha+3\gamma}n! D^{p}$ n.m.D∈ℕ n>7 and$\gamma$= 0 or 1 $\alpha=0 or 1 or 2 $ 
 with conductor N=$2^{2+2\alpha} n!\prod_{p|D^{p}}$  for a large n we have that N is divisible by many odd prime if we assume that $n!<p $this mean thap p  does not divide n! and the level of of the cusp predict by Ribet theorem is equale to 4 or 16 and no modular fom exist of this two level .this is true or not whay ?

Comment: I found this question very hard to understand, not even just mathematically (for example, I don't know what 'that' is in "why that is true?" at the end).  I have done my best to clean up the TeX and language without changing the meaning, but please feel free to revert if I got something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ribet's theorem works regardless whether $p$ divides $abc$ or not. So $E$ is not modular. However, $E$ is modular by the theorem of Taylor and Wiles. So $E$ does not exist, and Fermat's Last Theorem is proven.

Comment: But what about my example

Comment: @Abdallahchaibeddrra: It is not clear to me what your question is. Ribet's paper is from 1990, while Frey's paper is from 1986. Ribet has no condition on $a,b,c$. If you are interested in Ribet's theorem, then you need to read his paper, not Frey's.

Comment: @ Gh from Mo no i mean the paper of G.frey but the most important thing for me is my example above can you answer it

Comment: @Abdallahchaibeddrra: I cannot answer a question that I don't understand. Perhaps ask your question in a different language. Anyways, if you are interested in Frey's paper, then why do you bring up Ribet's paper? Ribet proved that Frey's curve is not modular (even when $p\mid abc$).

Comment: @ GH from Mo my question by other way. Compute the level (conductor) of discriminant $\Delta$ just that